# kotlin extention fragment activity has view with same id isn't ok

Tags: kotlin

`Activity` has `TextView` with id `tvAuthNum`, `Fragment` has `TextView` with id `tvAuthNum`, in code click jump xml is right，import xml is diff. But, run app `Activity`, `Fragment` use same `Fragment`'s  View. When debugging, I found memory address is the same in Activity and Fragment, why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full string for importing ids, for example:

// for the Fragment

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.<FRAGMENT_PACKAGE>.<FRAGMENT_LAYOUT_XML>.tvAuthNum
```

// for the Activity

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.<ACTIVITY_PACKAGE>.<ACTIVITY_LAYOUT_XML>.tvAuthNum
```

You have a collision between names.

Comment: for Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_fragment_header_card.tvAuthNum
for Activity 
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_drawer_left.tvAuthNum
i try,but activity use fragment'tvAuthNum,in Activity file click tvAuthNum,jum xml is right